# Using recursion to create nested folder structure - with example of integers

Tags: java, recursion

I am writing my PhD in linguistics and I wish to use a recursive programming method as a parallel to visualise a process. Recursion is important here, because this concept relies on the comparison of the concept recursion in programming and in linguistics.
Let us a suppose that we wish to write a method that creates folders and subfolders (and subfolders...) within them. For the sake of simplicity we could handle the folder names as integers and there is no need to create folders themselves.
I wish to implement this method with the following rules

- Every top folder name should be randomly generated as an integer between 1 and 999 (could be more, but it threw me a Stack Overflow error with larger numbers, but then my solution was flawed)
- Every subfolder inherits its name from the top folder, to simplify the process, every top folder has three subfolders and the names of these are generated the following way:first subfolder has the 2x the value of the top folder, second 3x and third 4x
- This rules applies to the subfolders' subfolders as well until they reach 999
- The program should count how many of these folders / numbers were created in the process

I tried quite many times and mainly every time some steps were missing or not working:
Version 1:

numbers here is a static variable of the class (list), but I would be happy if there would be a solution where I wouldn't need this.

```
public static void countFolders(int max, int currentAmount, int originalAmount, int index) {
    int[] evenMultipliers = new int[]{2, 3, 4};
    if (originalAmount >= max){
        return;
    }
    if (currentAmount < max){
      numbers.add(currentAmount);
    }
    if (index >= evenMultipliers.length) {
      countFolders(max, originalAmount, originalAmount, 0);
    }else if (evenMultipliers[index] * currentAmount > max) {
      countFolders(max, originalAmount + 1, originalAmount + 1, 0);
    }else{
      countFolders(max, currentAmount * evenMultipliers[index], originalAmount, index + 1);
    }
  }
```

I do think that somewhere along the way I miss some important concepts of recursion. I am not 100% sure how to keep track of the folder names of the previous level, but I tried this so many times with different approach (f.e. recursion within a foreach loop) and still no clue how to finish this properly.

-- EDITED --

[The input values are 4 as max and 1-1 as originalAmount and actualAmount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83wNT.png)

[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6sk4.gif)

This sample input produces the following output:
[1, 2, 2, 3]

But then it should be [1, 2, 2, 3, 3] (may be not in this order)
Because on the top level there could be three folder names / integers 1, 2, 3 and only the top level folder / number '1' can produce subfolders when multiplied by 2x and 3x
I try to make it more clear, I will introduce A, B and C to show on which level the current folder is, B is subfolder of A level and C of B level
So in case the max is 4

1(A) -> 2(B) and 3(B)

2(A)

3(A)

In case the max is 5 then the output is
[1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4]

But it should be
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4]

1(A) -> 2(B), 3(B) 4(B) and within 2(B) there is 4(C)

2(A) -> 4(B)

3(A)

4(A)

UGLY SOLUTION WITH LOOPS I only multiplied the folder values here instead of 2, 3, 4 only with 2 and 3

```
    public static void countFoldersNew(int max) {
    int actualAmount;
    for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
      actualAmount = i;
      numbers.add(actualAmount);
      int temp = actualAmount;

      while (actualAmount * 2 < max) {
        actualAmount = actualAmount * 2;
        numbers.add(actualAmount);
        actualAmount = temp;
        while (actualAmount * 3 < max){
          actualAmount = actualAmount * 3;
          numbers.add(actualAmount);
          if (actualAmount * 2 < max){
            actualAmount = actualAmount * 2;
            numbers.add(actualAmount);
            actualAmount = actualAmount / 2;
            if (actualAmount * 3 < max){
              actualAmount = actualAmount * 3;
              numbers.add(actualAmount);
            }
          }

        }
        actualAmount = temp * 2;
        temp = temp *2;
      }
    }
  }
```

EDITED:
A mind map how the structure should look when the input max is 10[image: Mind map Max value is 10]

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: I would find it useful if you would show a sample run with the method call populated with the appropriate starting values along with the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I just added these

Comment: I'm still not certain what the desired output is. Could you explain how each of `1,2,3,2,4,3,4` are arrived at, step by step, and their hierarchical relationships?. Also answer things such as `are 1,2,3 all at the same level?  which are subfolders of the other?` Even then, no guarantee I will be able to help. But more info is better and others may be able to assist

Comment: Sure! Really appreciate your help
This function represent a possible modelling option for a linguistic problem. My original idea was that let us imagine two parallel processes that run within the same folder. One process counts the existing directories and sub directories within this folder, while the other one creates them, this function is the one that creates them.
I introduced the above mentioned rules on how to create directories, in this function the directory name are represented by integers.
Here I have a methodological problem, how to write this code:

Comment: VERSION 1: should this function create all the top level folders a.k.a. numbers? In case the maximum possible value can be 4 (not included), then the first level directory names will be '1', '2', '3'.
Applying the rule on how to create subfolders, the function starts with for example folder '1' and multiplies this first by two and then by three (four would reach the provided max) and thus the first top level folder '1' will have two subfolders: '2' and '3', but the next two top level folders can not have any more, because 2 or 3 multiplied by either 2, 3, 4 would be higher than 4.

Comment: VERSION 2: the program should go first 'deeper', meaning that it should create first top level folder '1', and then its subfolders and only after this should it go and create the next top level folder ('2' or '3').

Comment: I edited the original post, I hope now it makes more sense (and corrected one mistake by the expected output for 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not recursive but I believe it works based on my understanding of the algorithm.

- folders from 1 thru max-1 are iterated
- add first folder to list
- now process subfolders of that folder
- add those to list
- repeat

Note that in some cases, the order may be different than expected. I recommend you verify based on additional cases.

```
for (int max = 3; max < 10; max++) {
    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int folder = 1; folder < max; folder++) {
        nums.add(folder); // add the first folder
        nums.addAll(add(folder, max)); // add subfolders of first folder
    }
    System.out.printf("max = %2d : %s%n", max, nums);
}
```

prints

```
max =  3 : [1, 2, 2]
max =  4 : [1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
max =  5 : [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4]
max =  6 : [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5]
max =  7 : [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 4, 5, 6]
max =  8 : [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7]
max =  9 : [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 8, 6, 2, 4, 6, 8, 8, 3, 6, 4, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

The method works as follows

- keep adding folders to list until folder exceeds size
- then process that list starting with next folder in list
- eventually the folder will be too large (and so will others) so return the current list.

```
    
static int[] multipliers = { 2, 3, 4};
public static List<Integer> add(int currentFolder, int max) {
    List<Integer> folder = new ArrayList<>();
    int folderIdx = 0;
    while(true) {
        for (int mult : multipliers) {
            int val = currentFolder * mult;
            if (val >= max) {
                // since folders are in order, if 
                // this one is too large, so will subsequent ones
                return folder;
            }
            folder.add(val);
        }
        currentFolder = folder.get(folderIdx++);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this (much nicer) solution. I have two concerns with it: Because of the true condition in while, the last 'return folder' statement is unreachable. The second one is that this solution doesn't generate numbers/folders within the subfolders. I added a picture of a mind map where the max condition is then, may be this way it is more understandable.
Thanks again!

Comment: You're right about the return.  I forgot to remove it.  But I am confused about your diagram.  Look at the top element `1` of the left.  shouldn't there be subfolders of `2, 3, and 4`?  You only show `2 and 3`.  And look at  folder number `2` on the left, shouldn't there be subfolders of `4,6, and 8`?  You only show `4 and 6`. That is the difference between your diagram and my generated solution.   Your diagram shows 21 total folders.  The one I generated has 24.

Comment: oh my gosh, my bad, I was creating this tree structure only for multipliers 2x and 3x, sure, this is a good solution.
Thank you my dear Sir, unfortunately you were victim of a not well thought through scientific process in which through new impulses certain conditions change.
Thank you again!